# Uploading objects to S3 using OCaml

Tags: amazon-s3, ocaml

In F# I use a library with this signature to manipulate data in Amazon's S3:

```
module Bucket =
  val exists : bucket:string -> bool
  val create : bucket:string -> unit
  val list : bucket:string -> string list
  val delete : bucket:string -> unit

module Object =
  val read : bucket:string -> key:string -> byte []
  val write : bucket:string -> key:string -> value:byte [] -> unit
  val asyncWrite : bucket:string -> key:string -> value:byte [] -> Async<unit>
  val delete : bucket:string -> key:string -> unit
  val deletes : bucket:string -> keys:seq<string> -> unit
```

I'd like to try to port my little program from F# to OCaml for fun but I'm thoroughly confused as to how you upload an object to S3 using OCaml. I found the [aws-s3 opam package](https://opam.ocaml.org/packages/aws-s3/) but the API is scarily complicated with all sorts of functors and stuff.

Given a region end point, access key, secret access key, bucket name, key and value how do I upload to S3? I'll be uploading lots of objects concurrently so an asynchronous solution using LWT or Async would be ideal.